# Zotac Nvidia GTX 560ti graphics card overheating

Tags: graphics-card, overheating

My graphics card goes up to 101 degrees centigrade on Batman Arkham Origins. The temp also keeps rising at random times when using Chrome or Firefox, ultimately leading to freezes. Media Player Classic also raises the temp, but VLC does not. What should I do?

**System Config:**

**Motherboard**: MSI 970A-G43
**CPU**: FX 6300
**GPU**: Zotac Nvidia GTX 560ti
**PSU**: Cooler Master Thunder 500W
**OS**: Windows 7 x64

Using latest Nvidia drivers.

This error appears after a freeze sometimes:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your fans and other ? When they get dirty, it can alter a lot their cooling performances.

Comment: I did clean everything. Another thing is that this might be caused by a driver update.. but I am not sure.

Comment: Downgrading the driver might be a solution. Just download the previous version on nvidia website, uninstall your current one and install the old one. It would not have been the first time driver update cause such problems.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how far back I have to go.. have been having these problems for some time now(must have installed more than 2 driver updates since the issues first started). Been ignoring the problem since I wasn't gaming much. But now, Batman! :(

Comment: why the -1? Tell me some reasons atleast.

Comment: Not my doing. Yet given you have had this problem for several updates, I doubt downgrading will actually solve it. Asking google (`gtx 560 ti overheat`), it seems you're not the only one having such a problem with this gpu.